# Subscript keyboard shortcut not working on Mac OSX

Tags: options, keyboard, mac-os-x

The keyboard shortcut `ctrl+_` for subscript does not work on Mac OSX (Swiss keyboard layout). If I use German layout, I can make subscript but no fraction. I've tested on different machines. It always gives a fraction instead, for which the shortcut is `ctrl+-`.

Comment: on my german layout I use `crtl+/` for fraction

Comment: And what do you use for subscript?

Comment: I use `crtl+-` as indicated in menu 'Insert'->Typesetting

Comment: I have a similar problem: On my american keyboard on mac OS, NONE of the control initiated sequences work on the wolfram cloud. It just beeps at me!

Comment: @Andreas I can confirm that with German layout these work. With Swiss layout however, both give a fraction :(

Comment: Look what is indicated in menu 'Insert'->Typesetting

Comment: @Andreas it is crtl+- which does not work

Answer (score 1):

On my Swiss keyboard layout and a fresh installation, I can use `ctrl-shift-6` to get the superscript box, and `ctrl-5` to jump into the subscript. It's a workaround, I guess.